# appearance of view in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, appearance

how to change my default behavior of view to different style like in [this](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#animations)(if you run it in simulator or in device).....
i am aware of those 4 methods available to appear a view like flipFromRight, left and curl....

are there any other methods

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [iOS Reference Library, UIViewController Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).